# Digital art and drawing cartoons is prohibited in Islam?

Tags: drawing

i used to draw cartoons and faces  when i was young but then i heard that its  a sin and prohibited in Islam. Many people believe and say that drawing cartoon character or non living thing, or person without soul is allowed. I want to know if that is true? Can I draw popeye? it doesnt have any soul. Is drawing something through digital is also prohibited? please help

Comment: i think Drawings were prohibited because people of those times draw their imagination and worship them. but now a days its irrelevant(if you or someone else is not using it for worship).  but as i do not have any reference of my claim i am putting it in comments.

Comment: "I think" without providing references would make it an opinion. @Zia

Answer (score 0):

No. Drawing is not prohibited at all.

According to the Hadith of 'No harm to your self or others' (لا ضرر و لا ضرار), so why drawings are prohibited if they don't hurt you or other people as long as you do them in a good manner?

Other Hadith, that, 'ask for knowledge from your birth to your death', if you want to learn scientific drawings like human anatomy, electrical circuits, and others, are Haram?

kind of such things are negatively impacting the purpose of Islam: doing good deeds and believe in Allah.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I suspect you will get downvotes as a lot of people downvote answers if its against the ideology and beliefs.

Comment: عبدالمئمن, although dear-user921 can be right to some extent, but I  reckon what you presented (especially: No harm to your self or others' (لا ضرر و لا ضرار) = Can be related and helpful issue. Jazak-Allah-Khaira, dear mate.

Comment: Actually, it does not hurt anyone if you draw a complete human, but is against God’s commands, if God Says no images, then no, we must listen to what He tells us to do. But He allows us to make images for education purposes only( e.g. if you want to learn how to be a doctor, you need to have a doll in form of a human) and that is allowed. And in here it is about animated things, it is only forbidden the animated things to be made, but if you have to, then you can make unanimated things only and that is totally ok to make.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum friends.. If drawing of anything having soul is haram,,Then flowers are also having soul... Or if drawing of non living thing is allowed then what about making sketch of different religious god statue... As we are making sketch of a rock statue which is non living thing, But its haram, cause non believers use to worship them... I think the thing which is needed to keep in mind is the prohibition of work having the feeling of sexual desires, feeling of worship or importance which may relates to shirk....

Answer (score 0):

Drawing of any animate object is haraam as EXPLICITLY STATED in the hadith...

Narrated Abdullah ibn 'Umar (d. 73H) radiallahu 'anhu: Allah's Messenger sallallahu 'alayhi wa sallam said, "Those who make these images (suwar) will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and it will be said to them, make alive what you have created." [Al-Bukhari 7/541, no.835; Muslim, 3/160, no. 5268]

There are other hadith as well

There is difference of opinion among the ulama as to whether pictures falls under the category of 'suwar' as mentioned in the hadith.

As for digital cartoons and drawings , I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

**In the name of God, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful.**

**Answer:**

**1)** **Your question:** Many people believe and say that drawing cartoon character or non living thing, or person without soul is allowed. I want to know if that is true?

It is true, in fact, this was told by angel Gabriel to prophet Muhammad. I’ll provide you an evidence. So here it is:

Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 7.841 Narrated by Abu Talha
The Messenger of God (saws) said:

> ”Angels (of Mercy) do not enter a house where there are pictures and dogs."

---

> Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 4.450 Narrated by Abu Salim
> Once Gabriel promised the Prophet (saws) that he would visit him, but Gabriel did not come, and later on he said, "We, angels, do not enter a house which contains a picture, or a dog."

---

**2)** **Your question:** Can I draw popeye?

I’m sorry, but it is not allowed. I’ll give you a Hadith for this.

> Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 3.428 Narrated by Said bin Abu Al Hasan
> While I was with Ibn 'Abbas a man came and said, "O father of 'Abbas! My sustenance is from my manual profession and I make these pictures." Ibn 'Abbas said, "I will tell you only what I heard from God’s Apostle. I heard him saying, 'Whoever makes a picture will be punished by God till he puts life in it, and he will never be able to put life in it.' " Hearing this, that man heaved a sigh and his face turned pale. Ibn 'Abbas said to him, "What a pity! If you insist on making pictures, I advise you to make pictures of trees and any other unanimated objects."

From this Hadith, we learn that it is permissible to make any image unanimated things. And if you do make any image that has soul, then you have committed one of the major sins.

The main reason for the prohibition of image making is because, it is an imitation, it imitates God.

> And Bukhari, Tirmidhi, and Imam Nasa’i relate the prophetic hadith form Ibn Abbas, “Whoever makes a picture, God shall torture him with it on the Day of Judgment until he can breathe life into it, and he will never be able to.”

The reason for the unlawfulness of pictorial representation is that it imitates the creative act of God Most High, as is indicated by the hadith related by Imam Bukhari and Imam Muslim that A’isha (God be well pleased with her) said, “The Prophet (God bless him and give him peace) returned from a trip, and I had draped a cloth with picture on it over a small closet. When he saw it, he ripped it down, his face colored, and he said, “A’isha, the people most severely tortured by God on the Day of Judgment will be those who try to imitate what God has created.”

---

I’ll provide you another Hadith that it speaks about image making. So here it is:

> God’s Messenger said: “Those who make these images will be punished on the Day of Resurrection and it will be said to them, ‘Make alive what you have created.’” [Bukhaari and Muslim]

---

> Narrated ’Aaishah radiyallaahu’anhaa: God’s Messenger sallallaahu’alaihiwasallam returned from a journey when I had placed a curtain of mine having images over the door of a chamber of mine. When God’s Messenger sallallaahu’alaihiwasallam saw it he tore it apart and said: “The people who will receive the severest punishment on the Day of Resurrection will be those who try to make the like of God’s creation.” **[Bukhaari]**

If you really have to make an animated thing, then you must have the following reasons:

> -passport.
>
> -driver license.
>
> -identify photos.
>
> -Photos of criminals for the purpose of identification and then arrest when they commit a crime or attempt to flee.

If you do have respected this list I have you, then there’s no sin upon you.

And if you really want to make an animated this, then God the Glorious and Exalted said,

> ”Who is more a wrongdoer than one who tries to create creation like My creation. Let him create a small ant or a grain of wheat.” [Muslim]

Here it means you can make any unanimated things, things that do not posses a soul such as: a car, rock, planet, stars, plains etc.. this is ok to make.

**3)** **Your question:**  Is drawing something through digital is also prohibited?

According to my knowledge, digital art is not forbidden, because it does not come under the prohibition of image making. You can draw any picture you want with condition not to print it and with condition not to make any woman naked.

I hope that I gave you a good answer.

The end.

---

**Sources:**

**-** http://www.islamicacademy.org/html/Articles/English/Picutres_in_Islam.htm

**-** https://salaficentre.com/2012/04/the-most-severely-punished-people-on-the-day-of-resurrection-would-be-the-image-makers-bukhaari-muslim/

**-** https://islamqa.info/en/365

Comment: Point number 3's answer is a breath for me. But I still have doubt about it. Where did you get that last answer from?

Comment: @KeepMove the answer it is due to my knowledge and logic. What does it mean digital art to you? An art that is made in a computer, not on paper or wall, but in computer.

Comment: Well, then. Unless you are a Mufti, then you can't make any faatawa. Drawing using software/ digitally is still under the category of imitating. So, it is still fall under the general ruling of drawing unless there are exception on the Hadith.

I think, what is called by drawing is the act, not the result.

Comment: @KeepMove In case you haven’t noticed, this isn’t fatwa.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the other answers here I can't help but sum it all in a 3 lines:

1- This topic is controversial among different sects of Islam.

2- There is no Aya in Quran that prohibits such thing.

3- The hadiths that do prohibit drawing might have been taking out of context. The hadiths might actually be about sculptures as these have been made into idols in that era. I highly doubt that 1400 years ago, the prophet said something about paintings or drawings at a time all the writings were done on the skin of animals.

So

Comment: no, they were in fabric too, and it was prohibited by The Prophet.