# Is it allowed in Islam to take comic books art as a profession?

Tags: fiqh, drawing, profession, art

I am considering to take a BA in Fine Arts with an intention to become [a comic book artist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ollLoBfp8jQ).

What does Islam say regarding this profession?

.

---

N.B. Kindly, **don't** post Quranic verses (either English or Arabic) inline. Providing links would be enough.

Comment: and, why is this question downvoted?

Comment: Well check the site and you will know that this is a question which has been discussed many times.

Comment: @medi1saif, why don't my question mark as a duplicate then?

Comment: Maybe nobody had time to check and mark it there's no auto-duplicate-maker this is the duty of the community. See for example https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24803/digital-art-and-drawing-cartoons-is-prohibited-in-islam?rq=1, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38046/can-i-draw-animation?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11153/can-i-draw-living-creatures-just-for-art just as a few examples (see also related links at the right hand of this site)

Comment: @Medi1Saif what is going on?! are you telling me it's sinful to work for disney in their producing their animated films? so watching frozen, rapunzel, lion king, etc is sinful? i mean, the films' productions were indeed sinful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniconism_in_Islam

Answer (score 0):

Drawing pictures of animate objects is strictly forbidden, and one who does so will be thrown into hell by a serpant especially if you choose a career that relates to drawing animate objects for a living. Your income will be haram, and I recommend you choose something along the lines of medicine which is a very benificial career for Muslims.

Comment: Please consider supporting your claims by evidences (see [answer]).

Comment: Why it is strictly forbidden to draw animated objects? Is this because in the era of prophets many people they used to worship and then God Almighty said: no more making portraits and statues of living things again?

Comment: It's strictly forbidden because it clearly says in the hadith that people will be asked to put a soul in the thing they created. So it's not only about idols, it's about competing with Allah. It may seem like an innocent action, and you might not see it as an evil sin, but as Allah swt said, in the ends of time people would not be able to see right from wrong. Islam cannot be reformed, we have to stick to the sunnah.  Prophet Muhammad, peace be upon him, said, “The people will see a time of patience in which someone adhering to his religion will be as if he were grasping a hot coal.”

Comment: @user3626314, what is your citation?

Comment: Bukhari 7.834, Bukhari 3.428, tirmidhi book of descriptions of hellfire hadith 3